# Can I get the video file in Camera roll on window phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, whatsapp

As I know, there is no way to get the video file in the camera roll.

But recently I did it when using updated WhatsApp.

Wahtsapp supportes video file uploading which is not in saved IsolatedStroage in wp7/wp8 devices.

How did it?

Now I'm researching but can't find.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

There is still no documented API for loading existing videos.

From [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/whatsapp-send-pre-recorded-videos-and-multiple-images):

> The ability to send videos has been in WhatsApp for quite some time,
>   but an OS limitation prevented the app from accessing the media
>   library to fetch pre-recorded videos. Since early 2013 though, Nokia
>   has been working with the WhatsApp developers and it looks like it
>   paid off to have friends in high places. Through Nokia’s assistance
>   (and indirectly, Microsoft’s), WhatsApp now has permission to grab
>   videos from your library to send to friends.